# unable to create webdriver object reference

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create webdriver object reference in the class which is not having main method. it is not allowing me to create the object. Finally, I tried with an instance and it is not working(not identifying driver)

```
public class LoginPage  
{
    public static WebDriver driver;
    static ResourceLoader loader = new ResourceLoader();

    public static String loginVerify(String username, String password)
    {
        System.out.println("navigated to loginvarify() :: ");
        logger.info("username is "+username);
        logger.info("password is "+password);
        try
        {
          driver.findElement(By.id(loader.getProperty(Constants.UserName))).sendKeys(username);
        }
```

Please help me

Comment: Selenium Version, Browser Type & Version please.

Comment: selenium 53.0, FF 39.0

Comment: where are you instantiating the `public static WebDriver driver;`?

Comment: inside the class as globally i am declaring

Comment: please help me. i am not getting solution from two days

Comment: few thing, put the code which people can understand. put the error message you are getting, without that it would be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: @PotnuruRavi did you tried the below solution which i have posted? Are you still facing issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LoginPage  
    {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/drivers/osx/chromedriver"); // path to your chrome driver
        public static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        static ResourceLoader loader = new ResourceLoader();

        public static String loginVerify(String username, String password)
        {
            System.out.println("navigated to loginvarify() :: ");
            logger.info("username is "+username);
            logger.info("password is "+password);
            try
            {
              driver.findElement(By.id(loader.getProperty(Constants.UserName))).sendKeys(username);
            }
```

I have updated your code, kindly refer you are missing your driver initialization. I have initialized to chromeDriver(), if you are using firefox initialize it accordingly.

> System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
>   "src/main/resources/drivers/osx/chromedriver"); // path to your chrome
>   driver

If you are not having the chrome driver, kindly download and place it in your directory path and pass the path reference accordingly. 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Let me know if you still face any issue or anything is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

WebDrvier driver = new FireFoxDriver(); //driver initialization
driver.FindElement(By.Id(IdName)); //to find elements by ID in UI

Comment: share your full code where you are initializing the driver so that we can find why you are getting the exception

Answer (score 0):

You can define your chrome driver path using System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Spring Workspace\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"); // path to your chrome driver or you can define the path in the environment variable so you don't have to use this setProperty code again and again......if you are using firefox driver than not need to define any setProperty beacause it is already defined inside org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver....